# How to differentiate numbers and strings

Tags: java, string, integer

I have a string

```
String s="Raymond scored 2 centuries at an average of 34 in 3 innings.";
```

I need to find the sum of only numbers present in the string without encountering any exceptions. Here the sum should be 2+34+3=39. How to make the compiler understand the differences between String and Integer.

Comment: The compiler understands what you tell him. Write a code that extract the digits from the string, and sum them. If you have a *specific* problem, we'll here for help.

Comment: You'd have to use a regular expression (or something similar to extract the numbers) and parse the numbers you found.

Comment: Thats' what. I need a piece of code that extracts Digits from a string

Comment: Try doing some research, googling this gives you many resources from which you can  learn.

Answer (score 5):

You should split input string by spaces (or by regex, it's unclear from your question) to the array of `String` tokens, then iterate through this array. If `Integer.parseInt(token)` call doesn't produce the `NumberFormatException` exception then it returns an integer, which you should add to the `numbers` list for further processing (or add to the sum right away)

```
String inputString = "Raymond scored 2 centuries at an average of 34 in 3 innings.";
String[] stringArray = inputString.split(" ");//may change to any other splitter regex
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (String str : sArr) {
   try {
       numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(str)); //or may add to the sum of integers here
   } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println(e);
   }
}
//todo any logic you want with the list of integers
```

Comment: Your code occur error if my string is like this - String inputString = "Raymond scored 2 centuries35 at an average of 34 in 3 innings."; here you split function will be failed.

Answer (score 1):

You should split the string using a regex expression. The split will be made between all non digits characters. Here is a sample code:

```
    String text = "there are 3 ways 2 win 5 games";
    String[] numbers = text.split("\\D+");
    int sum = 0;
    for (String number : numbers) {
        try {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(number);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //not an integer number
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: You are wrong, \d splits by digits, \D splits by non digits

Comment: `\D` is negation of `\d` (anything except numbers)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void sumOfExtractedNumbersFromString(){
        int sum=0;
        String value="hjhhjhhj11111 2ssasasa32sas6767676776767saa4sasas";
        String[] num = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0" };
        for(char c : value.toCharArray())        
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
                String val=Character.toString(c);
                if (val.equals(num[j])) {
                    sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(val);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum"+sum);`
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class MyClass {    
      public int addition(String str){
           String[] splitString = str.split(" "); 
           // The output of the obove line is given below but now if this string contain 
           //'centuries12' then we need to split the integer from array of string.
           //[Raymond, scored, 2, centuries12, at, an, average, of, 34, in, 3, innings]

           String[] splitNumberFromSplitString= str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
           // The output of above line is given below this regular exp split the integer
           // number from String like 'centuries12'
           // [Raymond scored,2,centuries,12, at an average of,34,  in , 3,  innings]     

           int sum=0;

           for (String number : splitNumberFromSplitString) {
               if(StringUtils.isNumeric(number)){
                  sum += Integer.parseInt(number);
               }
            }        
            return sum;
        }


        public static void main(String args[]) {
            String str = "Raymond scored 2 centuries at an average of 34 in 3 innings";
            MyClass obj = new MyClass();
            int result  = obj.addition(str);
            System.out.println("Addition of Numbers is:"+ result);
        }

    }
```

**Output :**

```
Addition of Numbers is:39
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are multiple ways on how to solve your problem. I assume that you are only looking for integers (otherwise each of the solutions may be adaptable to also look for floating numbers).

1. Using `regular expressions`:

   ```
   public static int sumByRegEx(final String input) {
       final Pattern nrPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
       final Matcher m = nrPattern.matcher(input);

       int sum = 0;
       while (m.find()) {
           sum += Integer.valueOf(m.group(0));
       }

       return sum;
   }
   ```
2. Using a `Scanner`:

   ```
   public static int sumByScanner(final String input) {
       final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

       int sum = 0;
       while (scanner.hasNext()) {
           if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
               sum += scanner.nextInt();
           } else {
               scanner.next();
           }
       }
       scanner.close();

       return sum;
   }
   ```
3. Using `String` methods:

   ```
   public static int sumByString(final String input) {
       return Stream.of(input.split("\\s+"))
               .mapToInt(s -> {
                   try {
                       return Integer.valueOf(s);
                   } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
                       return 0;
                   }
               }).sum();
   }
   ```

All cases return the correct results (as long as `null` is not passed):

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String sample = "Raymond scored 2 centuries at an average of 34 in 3 innings.";

    // get some 39:
    System.out.println(sumByRegEx(sample));
    System.out.println(sumByScanner(sample));
    System.out.println(sumByString(sample));

    // get some 0:
    System.out.println(sumByRegEx(""));
    System.out.println(sumByScanner(""));
    System.out.println(sumByString(""));

    // some "bad" examples, RegEx => 10, Scanner => 0, String => 0
    System.out.println(sumByRegEx("The soccer team is playing a 4-3-3 formation."));
    System.out.println(sumByScanner("The soccer team is playing a 4-3-3 formation."));
    System.out.println(sumByString("The soccer team is playing a 4-3-3 formation."));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should write a different function to check either it is a number or not for good as good practices:

```
public class SumOfIntegersInString {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
String s = "Raymond scored 2 centuries at an average of 34 in 3 innings.";
String[] splits= s.split(" ");
System.out.println(splits.length);
int sum = 0; 
for (int j=0;j<splits.length;j++){
if (isNumber(splits[j]) == true){
int number = Integer.parseInt(splits[j]);
sum = sum+number;
    };
  };
System.out.println(sum);
};

public static boolean isNumber(String string) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(string);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No fancy tricks: check if each character is a digit and if so parse/add it.

```
public static void SumString (string s)
{
    int sum = 0, length = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
         char c = s.charAt(i);
         if (Character.isDigit(c))
             sum += Integer.parseInt(c);
    }
    return sum;
}
```